# Density of states for free electron in one-dimension

Tags: statistical-mechanics, fermions, density-of-states

I am trying to find the density of states of a free electron in one-dimension.

I know that the result is given by $D(\epsilon) = 2 \frac{dn}{d\epsilon}$. However, I am unsure where this factor of 2 comes from. I know that there is a factor of 2 from spin, but shouldn't this be canceled out by a factor of 1/2 (maintaining $n >0$) when converting the summation to an integral in the following way:

$$2 \sum_{n>0} (...) \rightarrow 2 *(1/2)\int dn(...) \rightarrow \int d\epsilon D(\epsilon)(...) $$

where $\epsilon = \frac{\hbar^2}{2m} (\frac{\pi}{L})^2 n^2$ and $n$ is integer valued. We maintain $n>0$ for physical orbitals.

Where does the factor of two come from in the density of states equation, given that these factors of two seem to cancel?

Comment: Could you provide more details? What is $n$ and why it should be $>0$?

Comment: Generally the limits on the integration of energy start from 0. So, could be why there’s no half factor ( meaning that the n integral is also by default from 0).